# Supertest with cucumber framework

Tags: bdd, supertest, cucumberjs, web-api-testing

My team suggested to use Supertest for API testing. I developed an understanding through documentation. But i have requirement to integrate with BDD - cucumber-js. I am not able to find anything related to it, how to develop a framework with supertest and cucumber.

If anyone is using it or knows any tutorial/blog that can help me developing framework. Please share the same.

Thanks !1